# Branch merged, commit lost

Tags: git, version-control, merge, bitbucket

I currently have an issue regarding Git. My repository is hosted on bitbucket.org. I worked on a branch named `new-documentation`, I worked on `development` before, so it was equal to `development`. In the meantime, someone else pushed a commit to `development`. Nothing difficult, I thought. Later, I created a pull request on bitbucket. Of course, it had some merging issues because of conflicts. So I went into my console and manually merged the changes and deleted the `new-documentation` branch. However, when I pushed the changed `development` branch, not everything was merged into it. Can I somehow recover the branch or its contents? When I look at bitbucket, I can still see the open merge request with all its changes, when I click on "View File", I can even see my changes to it. But when I try to cherry-pick the revision, Git says it's invalid.

Is there any way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run git reflog and find the hash of branch new-documentation and create a branch there. 
1. git relog [And find the hash of the branch new-documentation]
2. git checkout -b [branch-name] [sha-you-found]

This will create a branch to where your new-documentation branch was. Now rebase it over development and merge development to new-documnetation and push.

Comment: Happy to know it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you did not execute `git g`c you still have it all on your machine (locally).
type `git reflog` and checkout the desired commit with your code, then create branch from this point and do what ever you need to do.